# Inclusion of three predictors that explain each other's variance

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, predictor, confounding

I would like to examine the relationship of a variable Y with a social construct.

There are three tests (A,B,C) that more or less characterise different aspects of the construct
(f.e., A= laboratory test versus B= questionnaire about everyday life, ...).
Also, the disadvantage that biases one test are partially resolved with the other test, and the other way around.
(f.e. A = bias because of reason x, but no bias because of reason y; B = bias because of reason y, but no bias because of reason x).

Because of this situation I thought that it would make most sense to include all three predictors into my regression model.

However, I am not sure what it means exactly when one of the predictors is significant. Does it mean that this is "the true construct with (all) influences of errors removed"?
If one of the predictors only becomes significant after I have included the other one (let's say, A alone is only significant in the presence of B), would one also say that it is because of the removed error variance?

I have also tested how the Tests are related, B and C are correlated signficantly. How do I handle this?